# Unable to resolve "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" Unable to resolve any other CSS file error

Tags: react-native, import, react-bootstrap

Nothing fixed it, i tried everything online.

I tried to use a different path like `./node_modules/bootstrap` etc. I deleted my node_modules an reinstalled it. I copied the bootstrap CSS file and put it inside my project directory and imported it but that didn't work either. Am searching for hours now and i am tired of it, hope someone can help me. I tried to install bootstrap 3 but that didn't change anything. It's like it doesn't allow a CSS to be imported. I also got this error, i was testing just a new css file to be imported but i got `Unable to resolve "./style.css" from "App.js"` Why is it not able to import a css/bootstrap file?

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
```

I guess react native can't import css files? But how do i then use bootstrap?

Comment: Pleas provide what you have done so far. And which file you're trying to import boostrap css to?

Comment: Abishek Aditya said you can't use bootstrap with react native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't use bootstrap with react-native as bootstrap currently only works with css. You can you a different library like react-native-material-kit

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so what are all the questions about? Is it because they are using react JS? I will further see into react-native-material-kit, was busy searching something like that thank you

Comment: @user9737826 It's because the way React for browser work in different way than React Native, they share some core concepts but the way they rendering UI components, how components react together is different quite a lot. That's why you're unable to import css like that.

Comment: @ToanQuocHo Okey that is clear now finally. I was trying for hours haha. But when i could'nt even import a self made css file i knew something was wrong. Yes react-native-material-kit looks good! Thanks for your time